# How is BLE data converted to UUID (and how can i convert it back?)

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

I am developing a BLE Android application that can receive small messages from a beacon. As a test I am letting the beacon increment a counter and send this as a string (service_data=str(counter)).

I see that the data I am receiving is changing but I do not know how to interpret it. I hoped someone could help me out on this part.

The first message I get is:
`mServiceData={00003031-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[]}`
which I assume is `10` (`0x30 0x31`)

This then starts counting up until
`mServiceData={00003839-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[]}`
which I assume is `98` (`0x38 0x39`)

However, after this the ServiceData changes and starts using the array(?) at the end:
`mServiceData={00003031-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb=[48]}`

Can someone explain how I can get the original string based on this ServiceData?

Comment: They look like the UUIDs which have nothing to do with the data itself. I'm wondering why you're sending something as a string. If you have an characteristic that is selected to represent a certain variable, there is no need to send "bulky" ASCII data. I'm also wondering how you're "letting" the beacon increment a value and send it as a string. Are you developing embedded code at the beacon end too?

Comment: Data is generally *not* converted to a UUID.  Rather, a UUID identifies the source or element of associated data.  You need to use the edit button to pretty much entirely re-write this - explain exactly what the transmitter does, exactly what the receiver does, and what your problem is.  It also looks like this may be a purely software question which would be more at home on Stackoverflow - though until rewritten, it doesn't really fit on any stack exchange site.

Comment: @DiBosco Good point! yes, we are using a LoPy to act as a beacon, in the end some of these will be used to broadcast measurements. A phone will then collect the broadcasts and send this to a PHP endpoint. As a test a simple broadcast was set up by using:

bluetooth.set_advertisement(name='test', service_uuid='1234567890123456', service_data=str(counter))

The counter is incremented by 1 after broadcasting.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for the feedback! I'm not very well known with the difference in forums. I found most questions about ble were on this forum, when does something exactly belong on this stack exchange instead of stackoverflow?